# Calender Questions empirical or classical probability?

Tags: probability

Questions like what is probability for monday to occur on year 2016 , i am confused wether such calender based questions are empirical (experimental) or Classical Probability. 

My teacher says that it is experimental for system of years is fixed observing revolutions of heavenly bodies but i feel thats just a fixation of unit and since **WE** are not doing the experiments , simply calculating , it should be Classical Probability. Please give me your much needed conformation.

Comment: I know nothing about probability or physics, but I sure hope Mondays occur in 2016.

Comment: Even without maths, it's clearly fact base. Monday will be there. If you had asked *will it rain on Mondays of 2016*, now that sounds more like a probability base :)

Comment: @GitGud :  no you didnt get it correct . We have to consider that wether year is leap or not and then calculate nos. of mondays & divide by total nos. of days in that year , so its not that simple :)

Comment: @bonCodigo : Same reply to you (see above)

Comment: *to consider that wether year is leap or not and then calculate nos. of mondays & divide by total nos. of days in that year* might be useful to compute the probability that a day in 2016 chosen uniformly at random is a Monday. This is definitely not what you asked about, hence GitGud's and bonCodigo's comments are spot on (and I cannot escape the feeling that you could listen more carefully to what people are explaining).

Answer (score 0):

*Typical* year has 365 days. A leap year has 366 days. That means exact 7 days summing up to 52 weeks + one or two days extra. That's the common facts without Maths...or rather with addition if you may..

So how many days the year 2016 has *exactly*?

> Now if the year starts on a Monday in a non-leap year, you end up with 53 Mondays. Or if either of the first two days lands on a Monday during a leap year, then you can also get 53 Mondays.

To say can you get 50 Mondays? 40 Mondays? No you can't!

- [Now how many Mondays in 2016?](http://www.convertunits.com/dates/howmany/Mondays-in-2013)
- [Another....](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20061231053951AALuGqK)

Getting 52 Mondays is not a *chance*. Yet, getting 53 Mondays can be interpretted via probability with the above `ifs`.

PS: Giving you this reference to take a look.